# Interface for populated docs mongoose 7.3.x

Tags: mongoose

Let's say I have model `User` like bellow

```js
import { Schema, model, Types, HydratedDocument } from "mongoose";

interface IUser {
  _id: Types.ObjectId;
  name: string;
  parent: Types.ObjectId;
}

interface IUserPopulate {
  parent: IUser;
}

type MergePopulate<I, IP> = Omit<HydratedDocument<I>, keyof IP> & IP;

const UserSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
  name: String,
  parent: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "users" },
});

const UserModel = model("users", UserSchema);
```

then I find users by the method `UserModel#find`

```js
async function getUser() {
  const users = await UserModel.find().populate<IUserPopulate>("parent");
  users.forEach((user) => {
    processUser(user);
  });
}
```

and function process user accepts populated user's docs

```js
async function processUser(user: MergePopulate<IUser, IUserPopulate>) {
//do some thing
}
```

Typescript accept user docs when I use `find()` but don't accept if I use `findOne` or `findById`

```js
const user = await UserModel.findOne().populate<IUserPopulate>("parent");

processUser(user); //throw alot of error here
```

How can I define Interface for both query?

Note It's work for mongoose < 7, I just got this error when upgrade mongoose to 7.3.0

Answer (score 1):

`findOne` and `findById` return a document or `null`, so you must add a test to eliminate the case where they return `null`:

```
const user = await UserModel.findOne().populate<IUserPopulate>("parent");
if(user) {
  processUser(user);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZQMYAsCmICGAaOECAE0wBsCAVATzEwGcCAJa4qHGTYgEQlQFcQmAHbwAvnABmUCCDgAiIsIDmECPUzyA3ACgdwUZiiScqTHACSAVQ1REOuHAD6wYgC44NOvQB0AeQAjACtMVBgLYl1HYRwhD3oYKANlKLgwHCgRGA8vBn9g0PDInTE9A05jU3NrWwAFCDB+Mg5zBAc0jKyPGqNdUp0YWnMAWSNlTHrG5s4AHgsCC1qAPjgAXjg-EGAYGZY2Fp4+QSy5pYIAa0xqCElLZbgAMjvdHVQIYQS4GyM0LFw1uDCTAAdxQGGwODm3ygSwAFG1orFMB5kIlknh2ulMqIPEhBnQUeDcD5cr5AiEwhECJlJB55PxbPR5HAxBixABKF5vD7waHDEjkAFEUhkWH0xnyAjQ34Qzl6HD0ajCVBSfjKmDAd5pGRmej0aGwhlGDyjKDjSZNFpQ2wLaEW6aYJbs+wAehdxAgcHosnMMHQyRK8sVytV6s1wjg4xgBudCLg3M+Rqg9ABOGBOG2X1s-JFPkkBmIsPZPkgUytPSg9pacPkWKy8jljiTvkk0AAoqZ0LDDbZnasVnHHGAdQx9bYe0ZGyy5f0E-Ak6n05m+QKyHmC34gUWSw1LbMK1XODW66IGy9gJIJ1BY5iR3qDUm5SUgA)

Comment: I already check null

Comment: @luongvy I added a playground, in the code you've posted there is no check

Comment: Hi Fraction, like I said, it's work for version <7 but in version >7 there are some change in mongoose type definition and there are 2 separate type return from model#find and model#findOne

Comment: `model#find` returns an array of documents, `model#findOne` returns one document or `null`, it's not the same thing

Comment: I know so I use #forEach. Please install mongoose@7.3.0 on your local if you would like to help. Thanks

Comment: @luongvy Can you provide a [minimum reproduction repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/wtf-is-a-minimum-reproduction) so we can help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Found it

```js
type MergePopulate<I, IP> = Omit<Document<unknown, {}, I & {
    _id: Types.ObjectId
  }> & Omit<I & {
    _id: Types.ObjectId
  } & Required<{
    _id: Types.ObjectId
  }>, never>, keyof IP> & IP
```

And then I can use interface of merge populate for populated docs